# How can I append only non-null items to a list in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using a path, I would like to get a list of tags for each node.
A case statement is used to save the tag's value only if it exists in the node, otherwise, it is null.

**My goal is to return tags with non-null values!**

Here is my Cypher query:

```
match p=(n)-[:ACCESS*]->(leaf)
where not ()-->(n) and not (leaf)-->()
with nodes(p) as nodes ,leaf
UNWIND nodes AS nodes_list
match (nodes_list)
with (
Case
When EXISTS(nodes_list.TagSet) and nodes_list.TagSet <> "[]" THEN nodes_list.TagSet
When EXISTS(nodes_list.Tags) and nodes_list.Tags <> "[]" THEN nodes_list.Tags
When EXISTS(nodes_list.tags) and nodes_list.tags <> "{}" THEN nodes_list.tags
End
) AS tags, nodes_list, leaf

return [tag in tags where tag is not null] as Tags, nodes_list, leaf
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could probably use a mix of reduce and the + operator on lists.
I'm not sure I understand the relation between "non-null" and the string values you use in your query: "[]", "{}". Are those Tags and TagSet properties arrays or strings?

Comment: what is the the result and your expected result? Please also give us sample data to work on. Thanks.

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/working-with-null/#is-null-is-not-null